# Why doesn't the clear button aligned with the text in a UITextField?

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield

I have an UITextField in an UITableViewCell.
For some reason the clear button isn't align to the textField's text.
Here's my textField code:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
usernameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(22, 10, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height)];
usernameField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
usernameField.placeholder = @"Username";
usernameField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
usernameField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
usernameField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
usernameField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
usernameField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
usernameField.delegate = self;
usernameField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
[usernameField setEnabled:YES];
[cell addSubview:usernameField];
[usernameField becomeFirstResponder];
[usernameField release];
```

And here's the picture to demonstrate the problem:
[image: Screenshot]

Edit:
I also tried with `- (CGRect)clearButtonRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds` and still nothing

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What is your contentVerticalAlignment property? I've seen this issue show up when the clear button is center aligned but the text is aligned the top. Try setting your textfield alignment to the following:

```
usernameField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

Any luck with that?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, but now the text and the clear button are aligned to the bottom of the cell.
I this code you actually align the text, not the clear button.
I want to align the clear button to the center of the cell
Any suggestions?

Comment: It worked!
I just changed the CGRect attributes to fit to the clear button

Comment: Thanks. to clarify, I took into account the height of the cell and the text field, to correct the vertical offset.         CGRect newFrame = albumTitleTextField.frame;
        newFrame.origin.y = (cell.bounds.size.height - newFrame.size.height) / 2.0;
        [albumTitleTextField setFrame:newFrame];

Comment: This answer needs to be easier found. Such an easy fix.  Thanks Levi.