# Is it possible to allign clearButton of UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Is it possible to allign **clearButton** of UITextField?

I have added the button to the textField programaticly:

```
_usernameTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
```

But it's located a bit lower then the center of the text field.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: What about vertically alignment?

Comment: What about it? Is there a property for this?

Comment: It didn't do anything. The button stayed in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend `UITextField` and override [`clearButtonRectForBounds:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITextField/clearButtonRectForBounds%3a) and provide a custom rect.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the contentVerticalAlignment property for the field itself?

```
usernameField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

Originally referenced: [Why doesn't the clear button aligned with the text in a UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437884/why-doesnt-the-clear-button-aligned-with-the-text-in-a-uitextfield)

Comment: It didn't do anything. The button stayed in the same place

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I had subclassed the `UITextField` and override the function `clearButtonRectForBounds:`.

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TVUITextFieldWithClearButton : UITextField

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "TVUITextFieldWithClearButton.h"

@implementation TVUITextFieldWithClearButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
}


- (CGRect)clearButtonRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return CGRectMake(bounds.size.width/2-20 , bounds.origin.y-3, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);
}

@end
```